# How can I join two serilaizers in django rest framework that have a similar field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models in my Django Restframework. In my views I want to get all properties and for each property I get Profile data of that user who created it.

How can I achieve this?

example:

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     mobile = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     location = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Properties(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


#serializers.py
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'


class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = [
         'title','price','category','created_by'   
        ]


#views.py
class PropertiesView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer = PropertySerializer
    queryset = Property.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get profile data in your Properties, check below -

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mobile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    location = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = [
         'title','price','category','created_by', "mobile", "location"
        ]

    def get_mobile(self, instance):
        return Profile.objects.get(user = instance.created_by).mobile

    def get_location(self, instance):
        return Profile.objects.get(user = instance.created_by).location
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

if you want complete profile data then  -

first define the related name in properties model (createby field) like -

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ---
    ---

class Properties(models.Model):
    ---
  created_by = 
      models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = "abc")
```

and then use related name in serializers and also include it in fields such as -

```
class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    abc = ProfileSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = [
         'title','price','category','created_by', 'abc'
        ]
```

and if you want specific profile data then -

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'


class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mobile = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = [
         'title','price','category','created_by', "mobile",
        ]

    def get_mobile(self, instance):
        return instance.created_by.mobile if instance.created_by else ''
```

Comment: None of the above works for me. Case 1 err: Field name `abc` is not valid for model `Property`    Case 2 err: 'User' object has no attribute 'mobile'

Comment: ok I was confuesd with User and Profile Models Class., wait i will update my answer

Comment: check my updates answer to get the values of Profile data in Properties.

Comment: Replace  abc = ProfileSerializer() in property serializer with abc = UserSerializer() to get all the data from user model. This will however not bring data from profile.

Comment: You should extend the user class to create extra fields that for now, you are creating in profile model. Having a single table is always useful than maintaining two table for same data. Exting user class will have a sibgle source of information.